# Connect to C++ REST sdk SERVER on Windows from LAN

Tags: rest, server, localhost, casablanca

I have a server written on `C++ REST SDK`.

There's `http_listener` which listens to "http://localhost:34568".

When I try to send a request in browser or from the client to localhost it works fine and I get the responses from my server. But the point is to use the application in network. And here where the problem comes.

When I try to request the server from the other PC using `IP(192.168.1.103:34568)` I get `"HTTP Error 400. The request hostname is invalid."`

I'm aware that that could be some firewall issues but it's turned off. Also I tried to set port rules in *brandmauer* and it didn't help.

And even more! I got *XAMPP* running *Apache server* and when I do the same thing but with `(192.168.1.103:80)` I do get the response from *Apache* and have an access.

Anybody had something similar or somebody knows what the problem is about?

Comment: In case of somebody meeting the same problem I've got a solution! Just replace 'localhost' with '*'

Answer (score 1):

Listen to local ip address or to your network name (dns):
"http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:34568" or
"http://your_network_name:34568"
So, if you have multiple network adapters, you can choose which one.